# NGP in Finkelstein reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilic-substitution

The question is to find the product in the following reaction-

[image]

In the answer given, they have replaced Cl with I and inverted the configuration at that carbon(Finkelstein reaction).

But $\text{I}^-$ being a good base, wouldn't it first take away O's acidic H and then $\text{O}^-$ will show Neighboring Group Participation attacking the carbon with chlorine and finally resulting in retention of configuration?

Comment: I- is not a good enough base to deprotonate OH

Comment: How do you say that?

Comment: I- is really not a good base. The pKa of the OH proton is around 16. Iodide in EtOH does not give EtO- and HI

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense

Comment: Iodide is the very opposite of a good base. HI is the strongest hydrohalogenic acid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking too far ahead for a simple reaction. First of all, $\ce{I-}$ is not a very strong base to abstract a protone from alcohol. $\ce{I-}$ is the conjugate base of very strong acid, $\ce{HI}$. Yet, $\ce{I-}$ is a very good nucleophile. Therefore, the condition given ($\ce{NaI}$ in anhydrous acetone; $\ce{NaI}$ dissolves in anhydrous acetone and therefore exists as $\ce{I-}$ in solution) is suitable only for nucleophilic substitution reaction and also favored $\mathrm{S_N2}$ mechanism. Since the byproduct form ($\ce{NaCl}$) is not soluble in acetone, the reaction favors only the forward reaction:

$$\ce{R-Cl + Na+ + I- -> R-I + NaCl_{(s)}}$$

Since it is a $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction, inversion is the result ($(1R,2S)$ to $(1R,2R)$ with closed to $100\% e.e.$).

However, note that there is a neighboring group participation (NGP) possible in 1,2-halohydrins in certain reactions (Ref.1). As OP suggested, if NGP is contributed here (without strong base I doubt it though), the product from NGP is going to be the retention product with $(1R,2S)$ configuration. Thus, total $\%e.e.$ of final product is $\lt 100\% e.e.$.

**References:**

1. T. A. Geissman, Richard I. Akawie, "Rearrangements of Halomagnesium Derivatives of Halohydrins," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1951**, *73(5)*, 1993–1998 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01149a029).

Comment: While OP's mistaking iodide for a strong base is mind-boggling, he has a point - why NGP wouldn't change the picture here?

Comment: @Mithoron: I agree with you. There is a possibility but it is very faint. But worth mentioning it. :-) Accordingly I change my answer

Comment: @Mithoron What do you want it to do? Form an epoxide?

Comment: @Zhe -OH can well enough participate in SN1, but it's effect is much more transient then that, more like first step on the road to epoxide and then step backwards.